# Problem with color in \part heading

Tags: sectioning, color

Below is my code, where the myBox definition interferes with the color of the heading I define for my `part` style. Any ideas why the horizontal line in the \part heading becomes blue? I want it to be black. Looks like something in the definition of myBox enforces the blue color right afterwards.

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}'
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}    

\setlength\epigraphwidth{.6\textwidth}
\definecolor{myBlue}{RGB}{32,92,195}

\newenvironment{myBox}[1]
  {\par\medskip\noindent\arrayrulewidth=1.5pt\arrayrulecolor{myBlue}%
   \hfill\tabularx{0.95\textwidth}{!{\color{myBlue}\vrule width 1.5pt} X @{}}
   \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}    {\tabular{@{}l}\kern\tabcolsep\textbf{#1}\\\hline\endtabular}\\}
{\endtabularx\par\medskip}

\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
     \thispagestyle{epigraph}
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\partname~\thepart:\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
  \reset@font
  \parindent \z@ 
  \vspace*{-400\p@}%
  \hbox{%
    \vbox{%
      \hsize=7mm%
     \makebox(0,0){\put(10,-100){\fbox{\phantom{\rule[-4cm]{7mm}{4cm}}}}}%
         \begin{tabular}{@{}p{7mm}@{}}
        \makebox[7mm]{\scshape\strut\small\partname}\\
        \makebox[7mm]    {\cellcolor{gray}\Huge\color{white}\bfseries\strut\thepart\rule[-4cm]{0pt}{4cm}}%
  \end{tabular}%
  }%
\kern6pt
\vbox to 0pt{%
   \tabular[t]{@{}p{1cm}p{\dimexpr\hsize-2.55cm}@{}}\hline
      & \Huge\itshape\rule{0pt}{1.5\ht\strutbox}#1\endtabular}%
}%
  \cleardoublepage

}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\begin{myBox}{About Fairy tales}
Fairy tales are more than true: not because they tell us that dragons exist, but because they tell us dragons can be beaten  
\end{myBox}

\epigraphhead[450]{Fairy tales are more than true: not because they tell us that dragons exist, but because they tell us dragons can be beaten.\par\hfill\textsc{C.K. Chesterton}}
\part{A Test Part Title}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the declaration `\arrayrulecolor{…}` is global. Simply replace this fragment of your code:

```
\newenvironment{myBox}[1]
  {\par\medskip\noindent\arrayrulewidth=1.5pt\arrayrulecolor{myBlue}%
   \hfill\tabularx{0.95\textwidth}{!{\color{myBlue}\vrule width 1.5pt} X @{}}
   \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}    {\tabular{@{}l}\kern\tabcolsep\textbf{#1}\\\hline\endtabular}\\}
{\endtabularx\par\medskip}
```

with

```
\newenvironment{myBox}[1]
  {\par\medskip\noindent\arrayrulewidth=1.5pt\arrayrulecolor{myBlue}%
   \hfill\tabularx{0.95\textwidth}{!{\color{myBlue}\vrule width 1.5pt} X @{}}
   \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}    {\tabular{@{}l}\kern\tabcolsep\textbf{#1}\\\hline\endtabular}\\}
{\endtabularx\par\medskip\arrayrulecolor{black}}
```